# how to fix a private list being modified in another class

Tags: java

for a school project they asked us to make the dijkstra's algorithm. 
I have the classes : Node, Edge, graph and Dijkstra
using graph.getNodes (return a List) and storing it in a local variable in findPath (in djikstra)
after using find path graph.getnodes return a list of size 5 instead of getNodes is from graph.java 
findPath is from Djikstra.java

```
public List<Node> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}

public void findPath (Node s, Node d) {
        System.out.println("nodeSize at begining of findpath : "+graph.getNodes().size());
        List<Node> nodes = graph.getNodes();
        dijkstraTable = new Map[nodes.size()];
        //verify paramaters
        if(!nodes.contains(s)) throw new InvalidParameterException("the source node is not valid");
        if(!nodes.contains(d)) throw new InvalidParameterException("the destination node is not valid");
        if(s == null || d == null ) throw new NullPointerException("s or d are null");
        Edge edge0 = new Edge(s,s,0);
        Map<Node,Edge> map = new HashMap<Node,Edge>();
        map.put(s, edge0);
        int i =0;
        dijkstraTable[i] = map;
        //iteration > 0 
        while(!nodes.isEmpty()) {
            i++;
            if (i==nodes.size()) break;
            Map<Node,Edge> newMap = new HashMap<Node,Edge>();
            map = dijkstraTable[i-1]; //last iteration map 
            //get minimum last iteration
            Node min = getMinimum(map);
            //mark it as "visited" 
            nodes.remove(min);
            //add it to the path
            List<Edge> edges = graph.getEdgesGoingFrom(min);
            System.out.println("nodeSize in loop: "+graph.getNodes().size());
            for(Edge edge : edges) {
                Node key = edge.getDestination();
                if(!map.containsKey(key)) { //create it if doesnt exist
                    newMap.put(key, edge);
                }else { //make sure to have the minimum value
                    if(getMinimum(map.get(key), edge) == edge) newMap.put(key, edge);
                    else newMap.put(key, map.get(key));
                }
            }//endfor
            path.add(map.get(min));
            dijkstraTable[i] = newMap;
        }
        System.out.println("nodeSize at end of findpath : "+graph.getNodes().size());
    }
```

the output is

nodeSize at begining of findpath : 7

nodeSize in loop: 6

nodeSize in loop: 5

nodeSize in loop: 5

nodeSize in loop: 5

nodeSize at end of findpath : 5

it shouldve been a 7 everytime

Comment: Can you please elaborate what's the problem you are facing?

Comment: the private List<Node> nodes from the Graph.java is being modified when I am using a copy of it in findPath()  which is in Dijkstra.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```java
public List<Node> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}
...

List<Node> nodes = graph.getNodes();
```

You are modifying your "private" list in the method `findPath`. If you want to avoid modification, either use `Collections.unmodifiableList(nodes)` int `getNodes()`or create a new list in `findPath` and pass `graph.getNodes()` to the list constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
List<Node> nodes = graph.getNodes();
```

to

```
List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>(graph.getNodes());
```

This creates a local copy of the list in findPath method.

or you could change

```
public List<Node> getNodes() {
    return nodes;
}
```

to

```
public List<Node> getNodes() {
    return new ArrayList<>(nodes);
}
```

This returns a copy of the list in getNodes() method.